# Combining reinforcement learning with labelled data

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, supervised-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm attempting to train a neural network to maximise a function, where the network takes a time series as input. At each time step it will make a decision based on what it thinks will maximise the reward function, however I have a small portion of the data which is labelled with a good action which would be valuable to incorporate.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to blend the two approaches?

I was thinking of either pretraining using the labelled data, or at each timestep calculating two weight updates - one which encourages matching the labels and another from gradient ascent on the reward function. I would weight these dependent on time, so that the update based on labelled data has more influence at the start of training and less towards the end. Any pointers/papers would be appreciated!

([combining supervised and unsupervised learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231336/combining-supervised-and-unsupervised-learning) is the gist of what I'm looking for)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combination of RL and supervised learning is well described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03732.pdf). There is a lot of pointers in Related Work section as well.

In general, they combine the Double DQN approach with a supervised loss (they use a margin loss for that, but you can try to use cross-entropy, for instance). This allows them not only to learn the action values during training, but also to avoid behaving in an 'unusual' manner.